# Clearing Cache related to user data

Tags: 8, caching

Drupal's cache system is a complete nightmare causing all sorts of issues with my user sessions. To provide a couple examples

- Our navigation header block contains a link that takes users to a different link based on their gender. If they are male they go to this site, if they are female they go to that site. If I login as a male and then logout, then login as a female, the link is still linking to the male link. Once I clear the cache, this works as expected.
- We have an EventSubscriber on Requests using the EventSubscriberInterface that will redirect a user based on a custom field `field_verified`. If a user's field is marked as false, the event subscriber redirects them to a verification page. If I login with a verified user and then logout and create a new user (therefore not verified) the EventSubscriber never gets executed, so the user isn't redirected properly. Once I clear the cache, this works perfectly fine.

I have an endless list of situations like this where user data is persisted through different sessions and is only fixed by clearing the cache. I don't want to have to flush ALL the cache everytime a user logs in or creates an account as this is a performance issue.

How can I clear cache related to just the user objects and sessions?

Comment: The short answer is use [cache contexts](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts). For the block that might be adding the `user` context to the render array, for the redirect it might be using a [`CacheableRedirectResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheableRedirectResponse.php/class/CacheableRedirectResponse/9.1.x) with the same context added, and so on

Comment: Yes, but cache dependencies on the user should be avoided if possible because this creates a lot of cache variations (fills the cache tables). You can achieve both tasks mentioned with user roles and permissions, which can be cached more efficiently.

Comment: While I think this will help for the blocks, I don't see how either of these would solve the issue with the EventSubscriber not running at all...

Comment: The cache contexts definitely will work. I don't know how you would achieve the same goal with permissions.

Comment: The subscriber is not running because the result of running it is cached from the first time you ran it, but you didn’t tell the system to vary it based on something

Comment: @Jaypan You can vary cache by role/permission - it's less less granular than per-user so less cache bin entries and solves the same problem

Comment: Ahh, in that case, it's not a difference between using cache contexts and roles/permissions, but rather a combination of both, where the cache contexts vary based on roles and permissions.